# Recuperar archivos eliminados con git -rm

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Tengo un problema, cree un repositorio con git y lo subí a Github, luego me di cuenta que había subido todo el directorio incluso los archivos de las claves de las APIS que usaba.

Entonces hice un `git -rm` de esos archivos y `git commit` y los elimine del repositorio.

Pero claro ahora también me han desaparecido de mi carpeta local, ¿hay algún modo de recuperarlos en mi directorio local?

Comment: Una cosa importante: en el historial de git deberían aparecer los diferentes archivos que se han añadido borrado en los diferentes commits, sería importante que quites esos commits con información sensible (contraseñas y claves de API) del historial usando `git filter-branch` (más información sobre el tema en la [documentación de github](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/))

Comment: ¿Tambien aparecen en Gitlab y github?

Comment: debe ser también en GitHub porque el enlace es a su documentación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has un `git log` identifica el commit donde aun los tenías, copia la clave del commit y has un `git checkout clave_del_commit`, una vez esto en tu carpeta tendrás nuevamente los archivos en tu carpeta, cópialos y pégalos en un lugar aparte.

Una vez hecho esto regresa a tu rama con `git checkout nombre_de_tu_rama_principal` (generalmente master)

Comment: Al hacerlo me ha desaparecido el ultimo log y el `git log` solo me muestra donde se borraron los archivos y los anteriores, pero donde me encontraba y alguno anterior no aparecen.

Comment: No he entendido a que te refieres, en qué paso te atoraste o en qué paso sucedió el problema?

Comment: hice el gitcheckuot e hice un commit, por lo que recupere mis archivos pero elimine el ultimo commit en el que me hayaba, entonces ahora mismo mi situación es:
Localhost ====> Commit nº3 y anteriores, Commit 4 y commit 5 eliminados.
Gitlab====> Commit 5 y anteriores.
Tengo que grabar los archivos que borre en otro directorio(archivos de keys), traer los archivos de gitlab y marcar los archivos de keys como sin seguimiento al volver a poner en el directorio correcto.
Si mi hicieras un paso a paso te lo agradecería, por que la estoy liando mucho :(